# iframe tracking pixel security concern

Tags: html, affiliate

Our application makes use of various tracking pixels and the way the information is sent to the third party tracker is by using the IMAGE tag and appending the information at the end of the url.(IMGAGE SRC="https://abc.com/a.php?username=bob&cost=22).

The new 3rd party tracking pixel wants the above information in an IFRAME tag as shown below
IFRAME SRC="https://abc.com/a.php?username=bob&cost=22 IFRAME

Is there any security risk using the IFRAME ?

Comment: I don't see how it matters to the 3rd party whether it's in an `<img>` or an `<iframe>`.

Comment: It is the requirement from the third party tracking pixel marketing company that it should be an iframe instead of a image tag.

Comment: Ramu: that doesn't answer Jeff's question.  Why does it matter to the marketer if the pixel tracker is in an iFrame or in an IMG tag?  I would question the merit of that marketer's requirement.

Comment: It needs to be inside an iframe to allow for nested pixels.